# Write to Azure Cosmos DB using JavaScript Azure Function

Tags: javascript, azure-cosmosdb, azure-functions

I'm following this example.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-integrate-store-unstructured-data-cosmosdb

Instead of using C# as in the example, I want to use JavaScript. But I'm trying to figure out how this part is written in JS.

```
taskDocument = new {
    name = name,
    duedate = duedate.ToString(),
    task = task
};
```

I tried the above, and below, but both threw an exception.

```
taskDocument = new {
    name: name,
    duedate: duedate,
    task: task
};
```

Guess it is a simple task for those who know how it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The proper syntax for object initialization is

```
let taskDocument = {
    name: name,
    duedate: duedate,
    task: task
};
```

You then need to assign this value to the output binding, i.e. to `context.bindings.taskDocument`.

Comment: Thanks, yes I updated my answer with my final code. It is basically the same as the code you posted. I will award you with the correct answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Okay, it was just me being stupid.
It should have been like this.

```
taskDocument = {
    name: name,
    duedate: duedate,
    task: task
};
```

No `new` in JS :P

**Update**

Complete example.

```
context.bindings.taskDocument = JSON.stringify({ 
   name: name,
   duedate: duedate,
   task: task
});
```

Comment: Would you mind sharing the rest of your function code? I'm very new to how Azure works and am trying to set it up using Javascript as well, however, there are not many examples out there on how to accomplish it in JS.